# Accessing google maps area coordinates (suburb boundaries)

Tags: google-maps, maps, data-visualization

I'm trying to show some data about Australian suburbs. 'Suburb' is the term that Australians use to describe an area, if you are from the rest of the world think post code or something similar.

I'd like to be able to get access to the area boundaries that are already in the map. These are examples of the kind of boundary that I'm talking about:

Marrickville, Sydney (2204): http://goo.gl/maps/QYRhx

Clapton, London (E5): http://goo.gl/maps/3an2Y

I want to be able to draw the boundary on the map, draw multiple boundaries on a map (e.g. show which areas make up the 'inner west'), shade the areas to indicate their vaue of something or other. Generally do stuff with them.

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088755/boundaries-in-google-map) asks about how to get boundaries that are drawn manually, but I want to access the ones that already exist.
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597683/google-maps-shading-of-australian-suburbs) asks a similar question, but it isn't answered.
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383147/uk-how-do-you-get-maps-of-council-locations-on-google-maps-like-twitter-does?rq=1) is similar, but the responses suggest using shape files, not getting them directly from Google.
- I've also tried the [maps styling wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html), and whilst the administrative, neighborhood boundary is what I need to show, it doesn't seem to be able to affect the map.

I've looked in the api docs to no avail. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Not sure if this will help in any way at all, but if these areas are not showing on the map then appending "District" to the search term will show them. If I type "Birmingham", it will just pin point the middle of the city, but "Birmingham District" will show a red border around the area. Maybe the term "district" is used somewhere in the API too?

Comment: It seems that district is related to the language of each country. Australia doesn't really say "district" much, so it doesn't add to the usefulness of the search.

The API docs don't seem to mention anything about admin boundaries at all.

Comment: I'm not sure its locality related. I've never heard anyone here say "Birmingham District".

Comment: There is an example [here](http://yuri.io/) that uses [topoJSON](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson) to draw the boundaries. I don't know how you'd get it onto Google maps, but you might be able to get it onto open street maps with Leaflet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't possible.
The area boundaries feature is not (yet?) implemented in the API.

Comment: is this feature available in api now ?

Comment: is this feature available in api now ?

Comment: Anything changed? Is the feature available now?

Answer (score 1):

If you explicitly need data *from Google* then I can't help you.

But if you just need data on Australian suburbs and don't care where you get it from (and if you happen to be interested in SA or NSW) then you can get GeoJSON or KML for SA from [data.sa.gov.au/data/dataset/suburb-boundaries](https://data.sa.gov.au/data/dataset/suburb-boundaries) and for NSW from [data.gov.au/dataset/nsw-suburb-locality-boundaries-psma-administrative-boundaries](https://data.gov.au/dataset/nsw-suburb-locality-boundaries-psma-administrative-boundaries).

You might find others at [data.gov.au/dataset](https://data.gov.au/dataset) too, I haven't searched that much.

Answer (score 1):

A repository that contains the boundaries of all Australian suburbs as individual KML files
https://github.com/aidanmorgan/aus_suburb_kml

On my site kerbsides.com.au I use the shapes database https://github.com/tonywr71/GeoJson-Data combined with Matthews Proctor AU postcodes to provide the shape and pin I need to draw this kind of map, calculate distances...

[image]