# Has Google Maps API been updated to include access to suburb boundaries

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

This has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485954/accessing-google-maps-suburb-boundaries) but I want to find out if this has been implemented since. Google Maps Javascript API v3 was released in June 2013, so I am hoping its been included in the new release.

Basically I want to

1. Show a complete list of suburbs surrounding a location
2. allow the user to select suburbs
3. collect the selected suburbs to be saved into a database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't even see an enhancement request for access to those in the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/)

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm very new to the Google Maps API and all I could find was the one question asked last year, so that's all I had to go on. I'll submit a feature request, perhaps I can get it added.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for this service in Australia you can use the surrounding postcode service provided by Find Postcode http://www.findpostcode.com.au/find-distance-of-surrounding-postcodes.aspx. This will provide surrounding suburbs as well as distance and a link to the relevant map.