# Get coordinates from Area name in Google map Api

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How we can get coordinates of area by giving the name in Google map API in Dot net framework? For example if i search Washington, DC, USA then Google map give me area coordinate of this.Any method available in Google map API in dot net?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing google maps area coordinates (suburb boundaries)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485954/accessing-google-maps-area-coordinates-suburb-boundaries)

Answer (score 0):

Google considers this type of information proprietary and does not expose it via their APIs.